# Insert data dynamically into table using enyo.js

Tags: javascript, enyo

I am getting 15names which i want to set to one table or a List by on-tap of one button.I want to insert the data by using for loop.So that i can get all the name after clicking the button. I tried the list.In this the names are loading on-load of list.but on click of button its not loading the data.so i want it to load in a table in enyo.js. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A little Fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/ntN6t/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: 'App',
    kind: enyo.Control,
    components: [
        {kind: 'FittableRows', components:[
           {name: 'header', kind: 'onyx.Toolbar', components: [
                {kind: "onyx.Button", content: "Load content", ontap: "tapload"}, 
           ]},
            {name: 'listplaceholder',fit:true,},
        ]}
    ],
    tapload:function(inSender, inEvent){
        var data = ['item 1', 'item 2','item 3'];
        for (var i in data){
            if(i%2){
                this.$.listplaceholder.createComponent({index:i, style:'background-color:#AAA;', content:'list '+data[i]}); 
            }else{
                this.$.listplaceholder.createComponent({index:i, style:'background-color:#CCC;', content:'list '+data[i]}); 
            }                              
        }
    this.$.listplaceholder.render(); 
    } 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the fiddle so the button tap calls the function to "load" the data. Which then gets bundled into an event, the event handler loads the list. You would want to do it this way if you're calling a service that calls back.

http://jsfiddle.net/pcimino/GnEBK/

```
handlers: {
    onLoadList: 'loadList'
},
retrieveData: function(inSender, inEvent) {
    // simulates getting data form a web service
    var data = ['item 1', 'item 2','item 3'];
    this.waterfall('onLoadList', {data: data});
    return true;
}
```